# For every ses $A \to B \to C$ and module $M$, there exists a ses $A \oplus M \to B \oplus M \to C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

> Let $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules. Prove that for any $R$-module $M$,
> there is a short exact sequence $0 \to A \oplus M \to B \oplus M \to C \to 0$.

Can anyone please help me with this? I don't even have a clue how to start. Have been staring at books for hours and I still don't have a clue.

Comment: If you have a map $f:A\to B$, can you construct a map $g:A\oplus M\to B\oplus M$?

Comment: cant you define g:A⊕M → B⊕M by g(a+m) = (b+m) for some b in B?

Comment: Yes, but you want $g$ to be related to $f$ in some way. for instance you may take $b=f(a)$. Using this particular $g$ you can get the desired short exact sequence.

Comment: Sorry to bother but I am still not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0\to A \stackrel{f}{\to} B \stackrel{g}{\to} C \to 0$ be an exact sequence of $R$-modules and $M$ any $R$-module.
You can construct a new short exact sequence
$0\to A \oplus M \stackrel{\overline f}{\to} B \oplus M \stackrel{\overline g}{\to} C \to 0$ where $\overline f (a,m)=(f(a),m)$ and $\overline g (b,m)=g(b)$.

Things you need to check:

- $\overline f$ and $\overline g$ are morphisms of $R$-modules,
- $\overline f$ is injective,
- $\overline g$ is surjective,
- $\ker \overline g = \textrm{im} \overline f$